# Scala - No instant converter found for type: scala.Tuple5

Tags: scala, jodatime

I have some line code:

```
import org.joda.time._
import org.joda.time.format._
val sampleDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

So I get a error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No instant converter found for type: scala.Tuple5
    at org.joda.time.convert.ConverterManager.getInstantConverter(ConverterManager.java:165)
    at org.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime.<init>(BaseDateTime.java:169)
    at org.joda.time.DateTime.<init>(DateTime.java:168)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:19)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:26)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:28)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:30)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
    at <init>(<console>:42)
    at .<init>(<console>:46)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1125)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:705)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:669)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:828)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loop(SparkILoop.scala:641)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:968)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1011)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I don't know why I get this error, although in this web: 
https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html
I see this the contructor is right....

```
   DateTime

public DateTime(int year,
                int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth,
                int hourOfDay,
                int minuteOfHour)
Constructs an instance from datetime field values using ISOChronology in the default time zone.
Parameters:
year - the year
monthOfYear - the month of the year
dayOfMonth - the day of the month
hourOfDay - the hour of the day
minuteOfHour - the minute of the hour
Since:
2.0
```

Thank you !!

Comment: Doesn't the constructor take 6 parameters instead of 5?

Comment: Sorry, this is a contructor DateTime

public DateTime(int year,
                int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth,
                int hourOfDay,
                int minuteOfHour)

Comment: It seems that the compiler treat the brackets within a tuple5, can you paste the full code section to see if there's any format error?

Comment: this is full code, I don't know while, I use spark-shell to run scala

Comment: i think, you're using the old version of joda-time as your code works for me with  `"joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.7"`

Comment: so how to know my joda-time version?

Comment: depends on your spark version and deplyment. You can find it in [maven] (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark) for example or inside spark's sbt-project definition (see "project" folder in your spark's installation)

Comment: so how can I update my joda-time ?

Comment: @ user3887341 1) please use `@dk14` to notify about your comment - otherwise I won't see your comment in inbox 2) just  update your spark mine "spark-1.2.0"  uses "joda-time-2.1.0" for instance

Comment: I think dk14 's answer should have been accepted. The fix proposed by him did solve the issue and his root cause analysis seems correct. I request @WilsonHo to accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works with [2.7](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) version of joda-time, but it won't work with some older like [1.6](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-1.6/org/joda/time/DateTime.html):

```
2.7: DateTime(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour) 
1.6: DateTime(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour, int secondOfMinute, int millisOfSecond)
```

as the API was changed.

My REPL:

```
scala> val sampleDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)
warning: Class org.joda.convert.FromString not found - continuing with a stub.
warning: Class org.joda.convert.ToString not found - continuing with a stub.
warning: Class org.joda.convert.ToString not found - continuing with a stub.
warning: Class org.joda.convert.FromString not found - continuing with a stub.
warning: Class org.joda.convert.ToString not found - continuing with a stub.
sampleDate: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000+07:00
```

If I try some inappropriate parameters:

```
scala> val sampleDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No instant converter found for type: scala.Tuple4
```

P.S. The joda-time jar is placed inside `lib_managed\jars` folder. So you can check yor version there. I have spark-1.2.0 and joda-time-2.1.0 respectively, so you should at least [update](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) to the 1.2.0 version of Spark to use the new API.